# celery beat running task on cleanup, how to stop it

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have bunch of celery beat tasks running at different times a day, but there is one particularly task at 8:00AM to send birthday messages which gets executed while beats cleanup happens at 4:00AM, so my task is running twice in a day. and I notice this happen when I restart celery beat the previous day. How to get around this and tell celery not to execute it at 4:00AM.

Comment: Take a look at [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial)